# Newtonian Square Root Java Program

Tags: java

I wrote this program to show the Newtonian method of finding the square root and then to run the math function to find that square root and print both of them out.  The math part is working well but the loop I created isn't coming up with the right square root for the newtonian method.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

```
package newton_sqrt;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Newton_sqrt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double guess, new_guess, last_guess, accuracy, n, x, absolutex;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter in N for Newton: ");
        n = keyboard.nextDouble();
        last_guess = n / 2;
        do {
            new_guess = ((n/last_guess) + last_guess)/2;
            x = new_guess - last_guess;
            if(x>=0)
                absolutex=x;
            else
            absolutex=-x;
        } while(absolutex < .000001);
        System.out.println("Newton = " +new_guess);
        double mth = Math.sqrt(n);
        System.out.println("Math.sqrt = " +mth);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Invert the loop condition. You want to loop while `absolutex` is bigger than epsilon, not while it's smaller. You want to *stop* when it is small enough.

```
do {
} while(absolutex > .000001);
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like math part need little tweaks, so does with loop condition. here try it, it works

```
package newton_sqrt;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Newton_sqrt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        double guess, new_guess = 0, last_guess, accuracy, n, x, absolutex;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter in N for Newton: ");
        n = keyboard.nextDouble();
        last_guess = n / 2;

        do {
            new_guess = last_guess - (last_guess*last_guess-n) / (2*last_guess);
            x = Math.abs(last_guess - new_guess);
            if (x < .000001) {
                break ;
            } else {
                last_guess = new_guess;
            }
        } while (n >= .00);

        System.out.println("Newton = " + new_guess);
        double mth = Math.sqrt(n);
        System.out.println("Math.sqrt = " + mth);

    }

}
```

Comment: by the way you dont need to declare guess, accuracy, absolutex and mth variables in this example